# Custum Keyboard Application Universal

Tags: ios8, keyboard, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

**Is it compulsory to make Custom Keyboard Application Universal?

Will Apple review team reject my App if there is no support for iPad device in my custom keyboard app?**

Answer (score 1):

yes your keyboars needs to support both devices iphone and ipad

source:
http://beta-blog.archagon.net/2014/11/08/the-trials-and-tribulations-of-writing-a-3rd-party-ios-keyboard/